# Undecorated JDialog / JFrame bigger than a decorated one

Tags: java, swing, jframe, size, jdialog

I found out that when placing 2 similar JFrames
in the same location :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(400,200);
        jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        jFrame.setLocation(new Point(200,200));
        jFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        jFrame.setVisible( true );

        JFrame jFrame2 = new JFrame();
        jFrame2.setSize(400,200);
        jFrame2.setUndecorated(false);
        jFrame2.setLocation(new Point(200,200));
        jFrame2.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        jFrame2.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

Where one JFrame is decorated and the other isn't, yields a decorated frame (in green) which is smaller than the undecorated one (in red): 
[image]

The bounds of the two frames are the same, as expected:

> JFrame 1 bounds java.awt.Rectangle[x=200,y=200,width=400,height=200]
>   
> JFrame 2 bounds java.awt.Rectangle[x=200,y=200,width=400,height=200]

I did not find what's causing it.

Comment: `jDialog.setUndecorated(false);` should be ***before*** `jDialog.setLocation(new Point(jFrame.getX(), jFrame.getY()));`

Comment: BTW - that is a code snippet, not an SSCCE. Add everything that someone investigating the problem needs to run it, without changing a single line of code (creating a class definition, adding imports etc.).

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for your comments. In the original app (where this problem appeared) `setUndecorated(true);` is executed before `setLocation(...)` . It makes no difference. I edited the code and tested to remove any doubt.

Comment: I'll have a closer look at it, when you manage to post an SSCCE/MCVE.

Comment: Looks fine on my machine. The positions are the same for both cases.

Comment: @Tom that's interesting. Can it be OS (I use a win 10 machine) dependent or IDE (I use eclipse Mars) dependent ?

Comment: When it is OP dependent, then it is more likely JVM and graphic driver dependent and yes, that can be the case. It don't think that the IDE has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is causing decorated and undecorated `JFrame` or `JDialog` to have different display size.

It is due to the insets. The size of the insets (which can be checked using `jFrame.getInsets()` ) of an undecorated window is 0, while the size of it for a decorated window is > 0.